# How to generate a list of PDE test classes?

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit

I'm experimenting with the example code of this [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-PDEJUnitAntAutomation/index.html)

I have a working example of the code but the author of the article says about the PDE test classes list :

> The PDE test runner process takes as a parameter a comma separated list of the test classes to run in a PDE test run. In the example code, the name of the single test class to be run is hardcoded i.e. phonebookexample.dialogs.PhoneBookEntryEditorDialogTest but the generation of the list of PDE test classes could easily be automated.

The code in his example use a single test class in the -classnames attribute:

```
<target name="run_pde_tests">
   <property name="test.classes.list" value="phonebookexample.dialogs.PhoneBookEntryEditorDialogTest"/>
   <mkdir dir="${test.reports.dir}/output/ws"/>
   <java dir="${plugin.dir}" classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="yes" classpathref="equinox.launcher.class.path">
       <arg line="-application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication -data ${test.reports.dir}/output/ws -dev bin -clean -port ${pde.test.port} -testpluginname PhoneBookExample -classnames ${test.classes.list}"/>
   </java>
</target>
```

Has anybody got a clue how I can generate a list of test classes with ant and give this list to the -classnames attribute of the org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. This is my solution. I point the test.dir.totest to a directory that contains the plugin. A fileset is created with java files. This set is converted to a space separated list an assigned to an ant property. This property is used in the java task to run the tests.

```
<!-- point to a directory with java files to PDE unit test -->
    <property name="test.dir.totest" location="/pathtomytestclasses/testplugin"/>
 <!-- Include all java files in the given directory and sub directories -->
 <path id="semantics.classpath">     
      <fileset dir="${test.dir.totest}" id="test.files">
           <include name="**/*.java"/>
      </fileset>
 </path>


 <!-- this will convert the java files to a space separated list -->
 <!-- ant place it in a javafiles ant property -->
 <!-- This property is passed in the arg line of the ant java task -->
 <!-- to run the PDE tests -->
 <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="javafiles">
      <path refid="semantics.classpath"/>
      <!-- this regex will create 3 groups -->
      <!-- group 1 is the path -->
      <!-- group 2 is the filename withouth the .java extension -->
      <!-- group 3 is the file extension -->
      <mapper type="regexp" from="^(.+)/([^/]+)$?.java" to="my.package.name.\2"/>
 </pathconvert>
```